# Autosave Excel using VBS or Macro

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am downloading futures data from my brokerage to Excel 2010 using TOS DDE and then retrieving this data onto a perl program. Everything works except for that I need to save the Excel sheet manually every time I need an update. Is there a way to automate this saving process every n seconds?
From my research on the net it appears like we can automate CTRL-S onto excel using macros or VBS but I am not familiar with either of them.

Comment: Research `application.ontime`

Answer (score 0):

You can record Ctrl + S and Excel will write the code for you. This can be easily modified to vbs.

So record your macro. Then create a autorun macro. Add this line to BOTH macros putting in the name of YOUR recorded macro, probably Macro1 if you don't rename it.

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"), "my_Procedure"
```

From help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196165.aspx

See the last section on this page to make it work. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Run-a-macro-5e855fd2-02d1-45f5-90a3-50e645fe3155#bmrunmacroautomatically

Comment: Thanx for your prompt response ..however when I try to save the macro i need to save it as xlsm file which my Perl program is unable to read from . Guess the Macro option may not work after all . Is there any other way to automate CNTRL S on the excel